# Toggling text of "a href" based on screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Using jQuery/jQueryMobile, I have a link as follows:

```
<a href="index.html" id="HomeLink" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="top" >Home</a>
```

I am trying to test various screen sizes, and if the screen width is less than 300px, I want to change:

```
data-iconpos="top"
```

to

```
data-iconpos="notext"
```

so I only get the icon. I have tried to do it with JavaScript:

```
var hl = document.querySelector('#HomeLink');
if ($(window).width() < 300) {
    hl.setAttribute("data-iconpos", "notext");
} else {
    hl.setAttribute("data-iconpos", "top");
}
```

But it won't work.

Question: can it be done in CSS instead.

If not: how can it be done in JavaScript?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YSzhg/7/

Answer (score 1):

You can't really set a data attribute with CSS as far as I know, but since you're already using jQuery, why not try it all the way :

```
$('#HomeLink').data('iconpos', ($(window).width() < 300 ? 'notext' : 'top') );
```

Remember to wrap that in document ready!

Comment: Thanks for input. Tested it and it seems to do the job wrt value of the icon-pos attribute. However, in the browser, the text does not go away. I am using jQuery 1.8.2 and jQueryMobile 1.2.0, if that is any issue...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way altering your code:

```
    var hl = $('#HomeLink');
    if ($(window).width() < 300) {
        hl.data("iconpos", "notext");
    } else {
        hl.data("iconpos", "top");
    }
```

with `.attr()`:

```
    var hl = $('#HomeLink');
    if ($(window).width() < 300) {
        hl.attr("data-iconpos", "notext");
    } else {
        hl.data("data-iconpos", "top");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for input. Tested it and it seems to do the job wrt value of the icon-pos attribute. However, in the browser, the text does not go away. I am using jQuery 1.8.2 and jQueryMobile 1.2.0, if that is any issue...

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the code in window resize event, eg:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
check();
})
$(function () {
check();
})

function check() {
if ($(window).width() < 300) {
    $('#HomeLink').attr('data-iconpos', 'notext');
} else {
    $('#HomeLink').attr('data-iconpos', 'top');
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for input. Tested it and it seems to do the job wrt value of the icon-pos attribute. However, in the browser, the text does not go away. I am using jQuery 1.8.2 and jQueryMobile 1.2.0, if that is any issue...

Comment: @user1897132  : I have reviewed the problem and found that jQueryMobile use the data-iconpos attribute value to modify the element but it happens only at the runtime (refresh of the page).
While you are modifying the attribute after the load of the page, So this method will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest using a different approach.

The `data-iconpos="top"` looks a bit out of place to me here. I have a feeling (perhaps I'm wrong) that you're attempting to inline your styling into the HTML.

Why not try media queries?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    #HomeLink {
        /* styling for HomeLink when screen width is less than 300px */
    }
}
```

This is a CSS-only solution. It works if the user decides to resize the screen after the page has loaded. Try resizing the "Result" frame in **[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XLTwP/)** and notice the color of the link changing.

Suggested reading:

- http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries

And here are the docs on media queries: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

**Warning**: mind ahem, IE below 9, ahem...

Comment: I agree that top was not the best choice here, "left" or "right" might be better. How can CSS be used to which between "notext" and e.g. "left" then ?

Comment: You cannot. My point was to avoid usage of `data-iconpos` altogether.